# Minimizer of a quadratic form

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, optimization

Suppose I have a quadratic form of the form:

$$q(x)=\frac{1}{2} x^T Q x$$

Now I want to find the minimum step length w.r.t the steepest descent. So I know the descent direction is $\nabla q(x)$. So I want to find:

$$\min_\alpha q(x+\alpha \nabla q(x))$$

So I expand and differentiate with respect to $\alpha$ right?

This is where I get a bit confused. I have:

$q(x+\alpha\nabla q(x))=\frac{1}{2}(x+\alpha\nabla q(x))^T Q(x+\alpha\nabla q(x))=
\\
\frac{1}{2}\left ( x^TQx+x^TQ\alpha\nabla q(x)+\alpha\nabla q(x)^TQx+ \alpha\nabla q(x)^T Q \alpha \nabla q(x) \right ) $

So differentiating this w.r.t $\alpha$ and setting to $0$ I get:

$x^T Q \nabla q(x)+\nabla q(x)^TQx+2\alpha\nabla q(x)^TQ \nabla q(x)=0$

Which gives me that $\alpha=-\frac{x^T Q \nabla q(x)+\nabla q(x)^TQx}{2\nabla q(x)^TQ \nabla q(x)}$

However this is not the correct answer. I'm not sure where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Usually this is done for symmetric $Q$, $Q=Q^T$. Then it holds
$$
\nabla q(x)^TQx = (\nabla q(x)^TQx)^T=x^TQ\nabla q(x),
$$
where in the first step I used that $\beta = \beta^T$ for real numbers $\beta \in \mathbb R^{1,1}$.
Hence we obtain
$$
\alpha = - \frac{ x^TQ\nabla q(x)}{ \nabla q(x)^TQ\nabla q(x)}.
$$
In case $Q$ is not symmetric, one can write your formula with a similar argument in the symmetric version
$$
\alpha = - \frac{ x^T(Q+Q^T)\nabla q(x)}{ \nabla q(x)^T(Q+Q^T)\nabla q(x)}.
$$